# Rearrange dataframe to add new columns based on value of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I would like to have the column ds_id (contains 4 unique numbers incl. ) merged into the columns c1, c2 (c3, c4… etc,.) like the below desired output. There will not be any need for aggregation as it's only restructuring the data.

I've tried variations of df.pivot_table() but I feel like I'm missing something. I haven't taken a stab at df.apply().

Current dataframe:

| user_id | ds_id | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 55 | 31 | 0 | 4 |
| 55 | 66 | 2 | 4 |
| 66 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 66 | 66 | 0 | 3 |
| 66 | NA | 5 | 3 |

**Desired dataframe:**

| user_id | 2_c1 | 31_c1 | 66_c1 | NA_c1 | 2_c2 | 31_c2 | 66_c2 | NA_c2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 66 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 |

Note: My question is not answered in  [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) as I want to create n duplicates of columns c1 and c2 (e.g. 31_c1, 66_c2, etc) with the values based in ds_id.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='ds_id', fill_value=0, dropna=False)`, then flatten the MultiIndex